# How to make equation display the equation number on the left

Tags: equations

When using *equation*, it shows the equation number on the right of the equation. I want the number (1) to show to the left of the equation:

[image]

The code used for generating it is:

```
$$\mbox{\sc OFFSET}_i=\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} size_j=
S-\sum_{j=i}^{M-1} size_j$$
$$=S-size_i\cdot(M-i)-\sum_{j=i}^{M-1} (size_j-size_i)$$
$$=S-size_i\cdot(M-i)-\sum_{j=i}^{M-1}\sum_{\ell=1}^{k}\ell\cdot \mathds {1}_{size_j-size_i=\ell}$$
$$=S-size_i\cdot(M-i)-\sum_{\ell=1}^{k}2^{k-\ell}\cdot\ell$$
\begin{equation}\label{eq:offset} =S-size_i\cdot(M-i)-(2^{k+1}-k-2) \end{equation}
```

> **How can I make it show the equation number on the left?**

Comment: Please don't use `$$...$$` it is not LaTeX syntax. As for the eqn number, see the `legno` class option for the document class you did not tell us anything about.

Comment: if there is to be only one equation number for such a group, it's more usual to have it either vertically centered, or at the top if it's on the left.  is this to be considered a group, or is it really desired to have only the last line numbered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if only one equation number is wanted for a group of related equations, the equation number is conventionally centered vertically, or placed at the top if the number is at the left.

the following example groups the equations with a single number at the center:

```
\documentclass[tbtags]{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{dsfont}

\newcommand{\isize}{\mathit{size}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\text{OFFSET}_i & =\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} \isize_j = S-\sum_{j=i}^{M-1} \isize_j \\

 & =S-\isize_i\cdot(M-i)-\sum_{j=i}^{M-1} (\isize_j-\isize_i) \\
 & =S-\isize_i\cdot(M-i)-\sum_{j=i}^{M-1}\sum_{\ell=1}^{k}\ell\cdot \mathds 1_{\isize_j-\isize_i=\ell} \\
 & =S-\isize_i\cdot(M-i)-\sum_{\ell=1}^{k}2^{k-\ell}\cdot\ell \\
 & =S-\isize_i\cdot(M-i)-(2^{k+1}-k-2) \label{eq:offset}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

by adding the `tbtags` option to `amamath`:

```
\usepackage[leqno,tbtags]{amsmath}
```

the equation number will be placed at the top left:

[image: output of example code]

**edit:**
as suggested by egreg, the string "size" has been made into a word using `\mathit`
for better (and more appropriate) appearance; a command `\isize` was defined to
assist the change.

Comment: It should probably be `\mathit{size}` throughout.

Answer (score 3):

If you want something like this

[image]

you can use an `align` environment with `\notag` in all non numbered lines.

`amsmath`, `leqno` option will add equation numbers on left side.

Note: I've changed `\mathds{1}` with just `1`. I don't know command `\mathds`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leqno]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\text{OFFSET}_i & =\sum_{j=0}^{i-1} size_j = S-\sum_{j=i}^{M-1} size_j \notag \\
 & =S-size_i\cdot(M-i)-\sum_{j=i}^{M-1} (size_j-size_i) \notag \\
 & =S-size_i\cdot(M-i)-\sum_{j=i}^{M-1}\sum_{\ell=1}^{k}\ell\cdot 1_{size_j-size_i=\ell} \notag\\
 & =S-size_i\cdot(M-i)-\sum_{\ell=1}^{k}2^{k-\ell}\cdot\ell \notag \\
 & =S-size_i\cdot(M-i)-(2^{k+1}-k-2) \label{eq:offset}
 \end{align}

\end{document}
```